# File upload how to extract this element

Tags: php, file

I have an HTML form with a file input field.

In the PHP layer, how do I extract the correct `tmp_name` value, taking into consideration that `tmp_name` is an array and that its size may vary?

Thank you.

```
  $data = $_FILES['option_value'];

  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value);
  }
```

The result is :

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string 'carre_noire.jpg' (length=15)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => string '/tmp/phpsUUxYC' (length=14)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => int 5809
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's fileupload is interesting when handling multiple files, and a bit counter intuitive.

It would be expected that each array element would contain the details of each file, however that's not the case - instead each key contains an array of that portion of the file(as you're seeing above).

The easiest way to get each element is to loop over one specific piece, and use that key to pull info from the other

```
foreach($data['tmp_name'] as $key => $val){
    $tmp_name = $val;
    $name = $data['name'][$key];
    $size = $data['size'][$key];
    $type = $data['type'][$key];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php